# How to implement dynamic view(Oracle) logic at runtime in spring boot application

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, dynamic-view

For performance improvement going with the approach of creating multiple views in oracle(for example 5 views with same column). How to fetch these view data dynamically in spring boot application or How to implement the logic in spring boot to fetch these multiple view data dynamically at a single entity class.

Why this approach: the base table contains millions of records & this takes times to fetch the records and to publish, So we created multiple views for the base table. All views will have same column name(for example: It will have totally 2 to 5 column) to fetch records like one view brings(1-30000) records and so on.

With single entity & repository class looks like not possible. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Splitting the same base table into chunks via view do not improve any read performance. It will be at best not slower than base table.

Comment: consider like base table will have 50 + columns but view will have 2 to 5 columns from that base table as using select query

Comment: But you wrote: *with the same column to fetch records like one view brings(1-30000) **records***

Comment: yeah i was trying to say all views will have same column(2 to 5 columns) from that base table. only view name will be differ.